# Can i use a .NET DLL to solve a MONO NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono, httplistener

I am trying to set the timeouts on a `HttpListener` using

```cs
HttpListener listener;

void Foo()
{
    listener.TimeoutManager.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
}
```

However this throws a `NotImplementedException` inside my Unity application. The TimeoutManager property was added in .NET 4.5, In Unity 2019.1.0a10 (with the same behaviour in 2018.3) i'm currently using the .NET 4.x runtime which currently [defaults to .NET 4.6](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRuntimeUpgrade.html).

To validate it was not me messing things up i made a seperate C# project targeted at .NET 4.6 and made the following program:

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpListener listener = GetNewListener();
    Console.WriteLine(listener.TimeoutManager.IdleConnection);

    HttpListener listener2 = new HttpListener();
    SetIdleTimeout(ref listener2, 10);
    Console.WriteLine(listener2.TimeoutManager.IdleConnection);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void SetIdleTimeout(ref HttpListener listener, int timeout)
{
    listener.TimeoutManager.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout);
}

public static HttpListener GetNewListener()
{
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

    listener.TimeoutManager.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    listener.TimeoutManager.HeaderWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    listener.TimeoutManager.DrainEntityBody = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    return listener;
}
```

Which runs as expected, and logs `00:05:00` and `00:10:00` respectively.

Now knowing that it actually works *outside* of unity I build this programm into a DLL and included it in my Unity project, hoping that calling `GetNewListener` would use the dll framework's implementation of the `TimeoutManager` and thus be able to set it. But this too results in a `NotImplementedException`.

Is there a way to get around the fact it isn't implemented in unity, using DLL's, or making my own implementation? Or is the only solution to try get in contact with Unity and hope they will implement it?

---

**Edit:**
I was reminded that Unity actually uses *mono*, and looking at the mono implementation of `HttpListenerTImeoutManager` on their [github](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpListenerTimeoutManager.cs#L55-L59) indeed shows the `throw new NotImplementedException ();`.

Now my original question still stands: Is there a way to overwrite the *mono* implementation with the *.net* implementation from the DLL?

Comment: Which framework are you targeting in your Unity Application?

Comment: @yenta Targeting .NET 4.6

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: 2019.1.0.a10, with the same behaviour in 2018.3.

Comment: Did you change your .NET Profile in Unity to a newer profile? You can change the .NET Profile in the Player settings (go to Edit > Project Settings).

Comment: I have. I was also reminded unity actually uses mono, which slightly changes things. I've edited my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try monkey patching the `TimeoutManager` method on Mono's `HttpListener` by using something like [Harmony](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony/wiki).

Comment: That looks very promising, thanks! Will take a look at it!

Comment: I just released Harmony v2.0rc2 which supports more use cases and is better documented:
https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony
Documentation: https://harmony.pardeike.net